# MySQL Substring Grab all but last three characters

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

Basically, I am trying to find the inverse of this command: `substring(term, -3)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SubStr(myColumn, 1, LENGTH(myColumn) - 3)
FROM MyTable
```

or

```
SELECT LEFT(myColumn, LENGTH(myColumn) - 3)
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it: `SELECT SUBSTRING(term FROM 1 FOR LENGTH(term)-3)`

Answer (score -2):

If you need it to match in a where comparison you could use

```
WHERE somefield LIKE 'term___'
```